# Why am I getting a NullPointerException on this "get" method of a linked list implementation?

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

This is my code. I ran through it by hand and I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting a NullPointerException.

The code is the following:

```
Node head;
int size;

public MyLinkedList() {
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

int get(int index) {
    // Get the value of the indexth node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1.
    if (index >= size) return -1;
    
    Node curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) curr = curr.next;
    
    return curr.val; // this is where NullPointerException is occurring.
}
    
void addAtHead(int val) {
    // Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list.
    
    Node newNode = new Node(val);
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
    
    size++;
}

void addAtTail(int val) {
    // Append a node of value val as the last element of the linked list.
    Node newNode = new Node(val);
    Node curr = this.head;
    while (curr != null) curr = curr.next;
    curr = newNode;
    
    size++;
}

void addAtIndex(int index, int val) {
    // Add a node of value val before the indexth node in the linked list. If index equals the length of the linked list, the node will be appended to the end of the linked list. If index is greater than the length, the node will not be inserted.
    if (index < 0 || index > size) return;
    
    if (index == 0) {
        this.addAtHead(val);
        return;
    }
    if (index == this.size) {
        this.addAtTail(val);
        return;
    }
    
    Node newNode = new Node(val);
    
    Node curr = this.head, prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    newNode.next = curr;
    prev.next = newNode;
    
    size++;
}

void deleteAtHead() {
    if (head == null) return;
    else {
        this.head = this.head.next;
        size--;
    }
}

void deleteAtTail() {
    if (head == null) return;
    if (head.next == null) {
        head = null;
        size--;
        return;
    }
    
    Node curr = this.head;
    while (curr.next != null) curr = curr.next;
    curr.next = null;
    size--;
}

void deleteAtIndex(int index) {
    // Delete the indexth node in the linked list, if the index is valid.
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) return;
    if (index == 0) {
        deleteAtHead();
        return;
    }
    
    Node curr = this.head, prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    prev.next = curr.next;
    
    size--;
}

class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    
    Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

The input for which I'm getting the error is:

```
MyLinkedList();
addAtHead(1);
addAtTail(3);
addAtIndex(1,2);
get(1);
deleteAtIndex(1);
get(1);
```

Like I stated above, when I run through the code by hand it works perfectly. Any ideas???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running it in a debugger and set a breakpoint on the line where you are getting the exception. Then work your way backwards.

Comment: If it's the *second* get(1) that fails, then you buggered up the list in  your deleteAtIndex method.

Comment: Your assigning a value to `curr` in multiple places & then, doing nothing with curr itself like in `addAtTail` or `deleteAtTail`

Comment: Echoing other comments - your `addAtTail` has no effect on the state of the list - _except_ `size` is incremented.  No nodes are added and size is incremented so likely leads to issues.

Comment: thank you all! your suggestions helped me get it to work!

Comment: @jattias96 Your constructor is irrelevant because it is setting `head` and `size` to their default values. Global references are initialized to default values in Java. For example, Objects in Java are initialized to `null` and primitive numeric values to `0` which is exactly what your constructor does. Since your constructor doesn't do anything else, you can simply remove it. The default constructor provided by Java will do just fine in this case.

Comment: Try will debugger mode & follow line by line